# Access custom field from another customization

Tags: acumatica

I need to calculate value for one of the unbound field (in my customization, I have created these unbound field) in SO Line grid based on two columns in line items. Out of these two columns, 1st is UnitPrice and 2nd is custom bound column created in another customization. How to access these custom field (*which is created in separate customization*) into my customization.

Unbound field in my customization-

```html
public abstract class usrMargin : IBqlField { }
protected decimal? _UsrMargin;
[PXDecimal]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Margin")]
public virtual decimal? UsrMargin { get; set; }
```

These value needs to be calculated as below-

Margin = 100 – ((“Std MFG Cost” ÷ “Unit Price”) * 100)

"Std MFG Cost" is that 2nd custom field created in separate customization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While publishing customization, Acumatica creates all code files in App_RuntimeCode folder of the website. First check, what is the FullName of your DAC extension declaring 2nd custom bound field via different customization project.

You will be just fine utilizing any class from App_RuntimeCode in a different project as long as:

1. class **FullName** is used or in your code file there is `using` directive for namespace containing class created in a different project
2. both customization projects are published on your local development website

Comment: I don't think I can use the Fullname of DAC extension which is created in different project in my custom project. And `using` will not work here as there is no dll, because the project is directly created using customization without Visual Studio.

Comment: Both options will work for you as long as you don't mess up with an extension library. Accessing custom fields declared outside of an extension library (code files are stored in App_RuntimeCode) can not be used in VS project as Visual Studio can not locate them during build process and therefore cannot build the library.

Comment: Agreed. It is possible only with the customization project created and written in Acumatica and not with Visual Studio, as VS will not be able to locate the files and will not compile.